# Removing a particular component from DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am working on a component which will act like a desktop screen. It can contain several app windows which will be resizable and draggable (i.e. **All the windows will not be identical**)

I decided to store the active window in an Array of window details Object:

```
const [activeWindows, setActiveWindows] = useState([
   {
    index: 1,
    title: 'App1',
    isMinimized: false,
    dimensions: {
      ...
    }
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    title: 'App2',
    isMinimized: false,
    dimensions: {
      ...
    }
  },
])
```

In my screen component, I am mapping over these arrays to render each of them:

```
{
        activeWindows.map((window) => (
          <AppWindow 
            idx={window.index}
            title={window.title}
            dimensions={window.dimensions} //Initial dimension
            handleClose={handleClose}
          />
        ))
}
```

`handleClose` is a very straightforward function that just updates the array to remove the target object from the list.

The issue comes when I do change my AppWindow position and dimensions and then I close the window, the window Object gets removed from the list but that specific component doesn't. This causes the last `AppWindow` component to be removed and the updated `activeWindows` data is mapped to the existing components which causes the content swapping (for example: If there are 4 active window and I remove window 2 (i.e. removing its object from `activeWindows`), then the object rendered in window 3 will move to window 2 hence the dimension and the position of my App 3 will change).

I am not sure if this is the best approach to tackle these kinds of scenarios, but my main aim is to be able to achieve this in a way that is memory efficient as well so that my DOM/VDOM doesn't get filled with unnecessary elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a [unique key prop](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#rules-of-keys) to your windows

```
activeWindows.map((window) => (
          <AppWindow 
            key={unique-key-for-this-window}
            idx={window.index}
            title={window.title}
            dimensions={window.dimensions} //Initial dimension
            handleClose={handleClose}
          />
        ))
```

It’s possible you could use window.index, I’m not sure if that’s a stable (the windows in the array never get reordered) unique key in the windows array or not. Keep in mind you can only use it if it never changes after a window is created.

If it’s not, consider creating a unique id when a window is added to the array and use it as your unique key.

Comment: Works like a charm. Used a fragment wrapping the AppWindow component and passed the window.index as a key.
One thing I am still confused about that why it doesn't work if I pass the enumerated index activeWindows.map((window, idx) => ...) As this idx is also unique

Comment: @ChinmayPant - this article is linked from the react docs: https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/ and should answer your question